# Sound channel crashes on iOS, unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine

We've noticed a lot of crashes from our crash reporter regarding sound. We have a game running on both platforms (Android & iOS), and this issue seems to happen only on iOS.

```
Crashed: Worker Thread
0  hunt                           0x58984e GenerateCombinedDynamicVisibleListJob(CullResults*) (ShadowCulling.cpp:602)
1  hunt                           0x5cb73b JobQueue::Exec(JobInfo*, int, int) (JobQueue.cpp:325)
2  hunt                           0x5cb73b JobQueue::Exec(JobInfo*, int, int) (JobQueue.cpp:325)
3  hunt                           0x5cb87f JobQueue::ExecuteJobFromHighPriorityStack() (JobQueue.cpp:612)
4  hunt                           0x5cb9a1 JobQueue::ProcessJobs(void*, bool*) (JobQueue.cpp:717)
5  hunt                           0x5cb315 JobQueue::WorkLoop(void*) (JobQueue.cpp:739)
6  hunt                           0x6e7baf Thread::RunThreadWrapper(void*) (Thread.cpp:40)
7  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x20a9b85b _pthread_body + 138
8  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x20a9b7cf _pthread_start + 110
9  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x20a99724 thread_start + 8
```

Our unity version is: 5.3.4f1 Personal edition, and here is the report with more info:
http://crashes.to/s/d1bf565d467

We didn't find info related with this issue.

Someone could give us some feedback?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you using a Thread in your game? This could also be plugin using Threads...Do you have plugins in your project?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be from occlusion culling as reported by many users.

https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/crash-in-generatecombineddynamicvisiblelistjob

Looks like only workaround for now (March 2017) is:

> "Removing occlusion data and unsetting occlusion in every camera stops the crash."

https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/game-crashing-frequently-due-to-shadows.390517/